# How does the web_sys crate works?

Tags: rust, webassembly

So after extensive searching and reading, I get WHAT `web_sys` crate is for and WHAT it does, but I still have no idea HOW it does it.

I had an impression, that WebAssembly code cannot directly call JS or access its objects/methods. Is my understanding wrong? And if not, how does `web_sys` do the calls to the WebGL/Canvas/DOM methods?

Also, more practical question. What (if any) is the overhead of using `web_sys` in comparison to just JS calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had an impression, that WebAssembly code cannot directly call JS or access it's objects/methods. Is my understanding wrong?

Your understanding here is wrong. WebAssembly modules can export and import functions from its host environment. By imported functions from the JS host environment, WebAssembly modules are able to call JavaScript functions.

However, there an issues here - WebAssembly only has numeric types. In order to communicate to JavaScript with richer types (strings, arrays, objects), these values must be encoded in linear memory, which is a shared memory that both the WebAssembly module and JavaScript can read and write to.

The process of encoding / decoding types into linear memory is automated using [`wasm-bindgen`](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/). You'll find that `web-sys` makes use of this package in order to allow manipulation of DOM objects within Rust.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I clearly missed the part about importing JS functions into Wasm.